# Which 3D model format contains all planes information?

Tags: cad, 3d-model

I need to extract all planes information(position, size, rotation) of 3d model in my own defined coordinate.

The model maybe given as .STEP, or any other CAD supported file.

I'm pretty familiar with 3d graphics, but it's my first time to deal with CAD file.

Is there any 3d file format having an advantage for handling all planes? If so, I would like to convert .STEP file to it.

Any helps?

Comment: Do you need planes or planar faces (because planes do not have a size)?

Comment: @Shrotter I need all points of a planar. Then I expect to calculate its normal vector and size for my own purposes.

Comment: Export formats like step or iges describe planar faces with there vertex curves and (at least in my test) with a plane definition (direction and position). I suggest you to create a simplified geometry and check out the export formats (open them in cad software again or analyze them as text)